# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

```
class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: "sks")

    var sceneData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe!, error: nil)
    var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

    archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
    let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as GameScene
    archiver.finishDecoding()
    return scene
```

---

So I'm getting a bug at the var sceneData = NSData saying: type of expression is ambiguous with more context. I'm very stuck

Answer (score 0):

`pathForResource` returns an optional.
`dataWithContentsOfFile` expects a non-optional.

Unwrap the optional

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: "sks")!
```

or do optional binding

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: "sks") {
 // path is safe
}
```

Actually the correct syntax of `dataWithContentsOfFile` is

```
let sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile:path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
```

and `.DataReadingMappedIfSafe` never needs to be unwrapped.

EDIT:

The full code:

```
class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {

    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: "sks") {
        // path is safe
        let sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile:path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
        let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as GameScene
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return scene
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Hello,
so I did make the changes and made it 
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: "sks") {
 // path is safe
}

but now it's giving me use of unresolved identifier 'path'

Also with the first option, the error remains

Thanks for the help:)

Comment: You have to put the rest of the code into the scope of *path is safe*. And I'm suspecting there is another issue returning `GameScene` while `SKNode` is expected.

Comment: `let sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile:path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)
        
        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
        let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as GameScene
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return scene
    }`

that is my full code, I'm very new to swift and I'm not sure at all how to fix it. I've spent a long time trying to